# My son has not started speaking properly, now he is 1 yr and 10 months

Tags: development, speech

My son is now 1 year and 10 months old and he hardly speaks. He calls Maa, Paa and very few words. But he understands whatever we say and is smart enough to do things. He will understand if we scold him or praise him.  He helps in our daily work, even if we tell him not to by saying that "You can't carry it, as it's too heavy." He is not ready to listen and wants to do it anyway.

I am bit worried that should I put him in a playhome with this condition or give it some more time until I put him in one.

Comment: Not listening to your parents claim you can't do something never actually stops, that's just being human.

Answer (score 12):

Please see [this PDF](http://drhart.net/clinic/forms/Denver%20II%20Developmental%20Milestones.pdf) called the Denver Developmental II. It represents normal milestones in development and is used around the world. The white area in each rectangle are the normals; the blue areas are the "late but not off the chart yet". Off the chart indicates a need to probe further.

[image]

As you can see (I've added the arrows at 22 months), by now he's delayed if he doesn't know 6 words (any words. "maa, daa, baa (bottle), no, etc. They all count.) He should be able to point out two things that you're reading to him or showing him (of all the pages, not on every page). If he points to a doggie and a cow, you're all set for that one. If he doesn't, he has 2 more months to pick up that skill before it's considered abnormal. If he knows any body parts ("Where are your hands? Show me!" "Where's your nose/mouth/head/(anything), he's good. If he occasionally combines 2 words ("Maa, no"), he's good. Note the top box: "speech half-understandable".

This gives you a rough idea of two things: what's considered normal, and how late most kids develop speech. Some experts do not even advocate diagnosing a speech problem before 24 months.

The PDF will show if he's on target for other milestones. Without asking you specifically (you can look at the chart yourself), I would guess from the bit that you say, that he's just fine!

So, enjoy the little guy for who he is: an intelligent, sweet, helpful little guy. Don't worry about putting him into preschool; it's fine if you do.

He has a doctor's appointment at 24 months, and if he has fallen off the chart on anything, talk to your doctor then. He may be an early bloomer in some areas and a late bloomer in others.

By the way, it's OK to fall off the chart in a few boxes (especially speech). It's the overall pattern that matters, and it's just a tool to let your doctor know if they need to *consider* any other tests. A doctor can usually diagnose a problem using this chart (asking mom if the baby does these things) and watching the child playing on the floor during the interview. **The chart is not a substitute for the trained eye of a physician.** It's just a guide.

Comment: Nice chart, I've never seen that before.

Comment: @Joe - I'm not surprised. They aren't handed out to parents, and they're a bit pricy. :) The developers of the chart hold a pretty tight reign on its use. But, it's on the internet now!

Comment: Is the data from the 60s, or have they updated it since then?

Comment: The DDII is the updated one. That is the one I've linked to.

Comment: Ah, wiki explains it was revised in 1992.  Thanks!

Comment: In Germany, the health insurance pays for your child to be taken to the doctor in set intervals for these checks. I find it very, very helpful to have someone professional do these assessments so you do not have to make those judgments ("any words. 'maa, daa, baa'") on your own.

Comment: @sbi Our health insurance pays for doctor's visits at these intervals also.  However, babies and toddlers aren't particularly prone to performing on command all of the things on these charts; hence why it is a good idea to do them on your own, so that when the doctor asks "Does he do ..." that you are ready to answer the question if he won't perform on command :)

Comment: @Joe: It would be a strange child who isn't eager to show off the ability to stand on just one leg. And a bad doctor who wouldn't ask you first I'd you've already seen the child do that. I remember the last instance of a specific pre-school-age test, where the doc turned to us asking "IIRC, your children would fail the next two questions because you don't own a TV?" Parents nod. Back to the child: "Can you tell me more about all these wonderful books your parents read to you?"

Comment: @sbi Perhaps a four or five year old, but at least for me with both of mine (3.5 and almost 2) they often become shy or uncomfortable at the doctor's office when asked to do things (performance anxiety?).  And while showing one or two things is usually possible, the entire gamut is not - particularly if they're 'just barely' at a stage.  How does a doctor identify that a child who has precisely 6 words has those six words - they're unlikely to say them on command, are they?

Comment: Of course the doctor should ask you if you've seen them - that is exactly the point of doing this at home first, though: to know all of the questions in advance so you can answer them accurately, rather than in a somewhat more stressful situation having to recollect exactly what your child can do/say.

Comment: @sbi - both of you are correct. For some of the earlier milestones (esp. language), we rely on the mother's observations. But it's easy to test the child, especially a toddler just a bit further on, and that is a fun thing to do, because often the mothers have never thought to ask their child to do some of the things on the test, like *stand on one foot*. We get to praise the child, the mother discovers a hidden skill, and is surprised and pleased. It all works out. But, especially for the earlier milestones (rolled over), we do rely on the mother.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, children are more shy the younger they are. I seem to have forgotten that. `:)` OTOH, while it is certainly not the only criterion by which to judge a child doctor, when such one can't make children laugh and cooperate willingly, it *might* be time to start to look for another one.

Comment: @sbi - that last comment is a strange way indeed to judge the competence of a doctor by, but it takes all kinds. I would venture to say here that you are judging the abilities of a doctor here very, very superficially. Time constraints dictate brevity, not social engagement with a baby (though it necessarily happens) and I don't *need* to make a baby laugh to see if it's a *normal* baby.

Comment: @anongood: Making a child cooperate willingly IMO is indeed a very important trait in a child doctor. A doctors who cannot playfully look into the child's mother's ear so that the child becomes interested to have the same done to itself will only ever look into the ears of small children who either try hard to wiggle out of their grip or who are screaming at the top of their lungs — both of which will lead to inferior results. But what you told in your comment above ("it's fun to do those checks") makes me think the idea is strange to you because you do not even realize you're good at this.

Comment: @sbi - that's very different than making a child laugh. But as a physician, I'd rather have a competent physician with so-so social skills than an incompetent physician with great social skills. Unfortunately, the average person can't judge how *competent* doctors are, so base their judgements on a doc's social skills. That's a mistake. It's also an age old problem in finding a good doctor. How does one know? All I'm saying is *you don't have the inside scoop on what makes a good doctor enough to tell someone to look for another doctor if x does or doesn't happen*.

Comment: @anongood: Hence my _"...while it is certainly not the only criterion by which to judge a child doctor, it might be time..."_ Also: IME there's a high probability the competent physician is the one who asks and can listen, who takes time to really look at a child (rather than just throwing this week's standard treatment at it, since they all caught the same cold anyway), who isn't over-diagnosing every case of the common cold, who, when asked, can back up convincingly whatever treatment they consider best, and who might change it after hearing new facts from the parents. No guarantees, though.

Comment: ("Making a child laugh" probably wasn't the best way to express skills in dealing with children. Sorry, I typed that on my phone while the bus arrived.)

Answer (score 1):

My youngest is also 22 months, and is definitely not "speaking properly" by some definition, though he sounds like he's a little further along than yours - he puts 3-5 words together ("Not do that", "Stand up", etc.).  Definitely not sentences or anything else I'd call "properly", but quite in the normal range for a child of that age from my experience.

There are definitely a variety of different ability levels when it comes to speaking; 22 months should be able to say some words, but it sounds like he's at that level.  Boys tend to be further behind than girls in terms of speaking, and if he's an only child (or a first child) then it's also going to delay things some in terms of sophistication (speaking in sentences, for example).

Putting him in a playhome (I assume this translates to 'daycare' of some form) will neither help nor hurt him in this area, as long as you're regularly interacting with him when he is at home; if you're busy (a lot of cleaning/cooking, or online education classes, or such) then it likely would help him; children learn to talk by hearing others do it, first and foremost, so if he's around people who talk more around him (both his-age and older kids, and the teachers) he'll be able to improve.

You should be seeing your pediatrician at around 2 years old, hopefully, and during that visit you should discuss this concern with her/him.  Your pediatrician is able to help you understand exactly what you should be concerned with.  He/she can test your son's hearing, which is the most common problem related to speech; particularly if your son had more ear infections than is typical for a child (more than 3 that required medication, I think) this is a good thing to check.

I recommend filling out an Ages and Stages questionnaire for his age, such as [this one](http://www.portlandpediatric.com/documents/24-Month-Questionnaire.pdf) which is appropriate for 24 months.  This gives you a checklist that will help you answer questions when you go to your appointment; many of the questions the doctor should ask are on this sheet.  Do not expect your child to do all of the things listed - it is intentionally including some things that would be well above age level (I've always felt as an honesty test, largely, though I don't know for sure) and every child certainly develops differently, so different children would be at different levels in this questionnaire.

All in all, I think that your son is not necessarily particularly behind in speech; but that doesn't mean you shouldn't stay on top of things, as if it turns out he is developmentally delayed in this area, the earlier you address the problem the better it is for his future.

Comment: Just a couple of comments. It sounds like your 22 month old is well within normal in speech, and speech is actually later but *more sophisticated* in secondborns and later.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Oh, absolutely - I was trying to explain that 'speak properly' isn't a normal skill at that age :)  As far as younger/firstborns, I have a limited experience here for sure, but at the daycare in the 2 year old room it was obvious which children were second-born: they talked in sentences well before the firstborns, almost exclusively, and girls same before boys (The firstborn girls talked in sentences at around the same time as the second-born boys).  Is that what you mean by sophisticated?

Comment: Sophisticated is exactly that; earlier sentences, earlier use of pronouns ("mine!"), etc. But the firstborns reach the 50-word milestone earlier, etc.

Comment: Hmm.  Interesting.  That probably explains the difference in my two then: my 22 month old didn't know his color words quiet as early (my firstborn knew how to say several colors before one, while my secondborn just in the last couple of months learned his last few rainbow colors; they both knew what they looked like)  but my firstborn didn't have the "Don't want that" as early.

Answer (score 0):

Not speaking properly at 1yr 10 months does not seem abnormal to me. I've met my girlfriend's daughter when she was a bit more than 2 years old, and she was barely saying a small set of words. At 4 years now, she never never never stop speaking... which is adorable but a bit exhausting. :)

I think most childs do not talk more than a few words barely recognizable at that age, although I do not have any source for that.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to far off. Also keep in mind: there is more communication than verbal. Does your child use signs? Or body language? Can you understand what he is trying to communicate?

If so, maybe he just prefers these methods over using words. My daughter between two and three was also not speaking much, but everyone commented on how easy it was to understand what she wanted because she was very good at using signs to communicate things.

She's three and a half by now, and she's talking without too much trouble now. As long as they understand communicating, they'll learn speech when they're ready for it. Not everyone enjoys talking, and kids might be just the same.